# Rails 4 and mongoid: programmatically build a query with multiple AND and OR conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

I want to be able to dynamically transform an input hash like the following:

```
{ name: ['John', 'Luke'], status: ['ACTIVE', 'SUSPENDED'] }
```

in a query that will put the different fields (name, status) in a AND relationship, and the values for each field in a OR relationship. In SQL that would be something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM my_class 
WHERE (name LIKE 'John' OR name LIKE 'Luke') 
AND (status LIKE 'ACTIVE' OR status LIKE 'SUSPENDED')
```

I've tried different approaches but I'm kind of stucked. Here what works for one field with multiple values:

```
def search(criteria)
    result = MyClass.all

    criteria.each do |field, values|
      values = [values] unless values.respond_to?(:each)

      conditions = []
      values.each do |v|
        conditions << { field => v } unless v.empty?
      end

      result = result.or(conditions) # this is enough for one field only, but how to create an AND condition with the second field (and so on)?
    end

    result
  end
```

I've read about `any_of` but it's not completely clear to me how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query you want to build is:

```
MyClass.where(
  :name.in   => [ 'John', 'Luke' ],
  :status.in => [ 'ACTIVE', 'SUSPENDED' ]
)
```

A `:field.in` works the same as `field in (...)` in SQL and that's just a short form for an or-statement. That makes things quite a bit easier as you just have to add `.in` calls to the `criteria` keys whose vales are arrays, something like this:

```
query = criteria.each_with_object({}) do |(field, values), query|
  field = field.in if(values.is_a?(Array))
  query[field] = values
end
MyClass.where(query)
```