# Rails 4 and Mongoid: programmatically build query to search for different conditions on the same field

Tags: ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

I'm building a advanced search functionality and, thanks to the [help of some ruby fellows on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20861936/rails-4-and-mongoid-programmatically-build-a-query-with-multiple-and-and-or-con),  I've been already able to combine AND and OR conditions programmatically on different fields of the same class.

I ended up writing something similar to the accepted answer mentioned above, which I report here:

```
query = criteria.each_with_object({}) do |(field, values), query|
  field = field.in if(values.is_a?(Array))
  query[field] = values
end
MyClass.where(query)
```

Now, what might happen is that someone wants to search on a certain field with multiple criteria, something like:

```
"all the users where names contains 'abc' but not contains 'def'"
```

How would you write the query above?

Please note that I already have the regexes to do what I want to (see below), my question is mainly on how to combine them together.

```
#contains
Regex.new('.*' + val + '.*')

#not contains
Regex.new('^((?!'+ val +').)*$')
```

Thanks for your time!

*** UPDATE ***

I was playing with the console and this is working:

```
MyClass.where(name: /.*abc.*/).and(name: /^((?!def).)*$/)
```

My question remains: how do I do that programmatically? I shouldn't end up with more than two conditions on the same field but it's something I can't be sure of.

Comment: What are the regexes that you have for names that contain abc and not def separately?

Comment: Okay, that's cool! I'm not entirely sure what you are looking for when saying 'how do I do that programmatically' (and ruby is not my forte anyway), but with regex, I would probably use something like this to combine them: `/^(?!.*def)(?=.*abc)/`

Comment: @Jerry when I say programmatically I mean that I don't know which are the conditions passed to build the query. They might be 1 or 3 or 5, and each of them may come with a series of possible values to apply. Thanks for your suggestion though, I will give it a try!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an [`:$and`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/and/#op._S_and) operator to combine the individual queries:

```
MyClass.where(:$and => [
  { name: /.*abc.*/ },
  { name: /^((?!def).)*$/ }
])
```

That would change the overall query builder to something like this:

```
components = criteria.map do |field, value|
  field = field.in if(value.is_a?(Array))
  { field => value }
end
query = components.length > 1 ? { :$and => components } : components.first
```

You build a list of the individual components and then, at the end, either combine them with `:$and` or, if there aren't enough components for `:$and`, just unwrap the single component and call that your query.